# `rails _version_` using incorrect version under ruby-2.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm trying to use a specific version of Rails (4.2.2) to create an application, but Rails is using the wrong version. This error only occurs when using ruby-2.2.1; when I switched to ruby-2.3.0 `rails _version_` behaved as expected.

When I run `rails _4.2.2_ new test_app`, the generated `Gemfile` version of rails is:

```
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5'
```

I have the desired version installed, but the `rails _version_` command isn't working:

```
$ gem list | grep '^rails '
rails (4.2.5, 4.2.2)

$ rails -v
Rails 4.2.5

$ rails _4.2.5_ -v
Rails 4.2.5

$ rails _4.2.2_ -v
Rails 4.2.5
```

Running `rails _4.2.1_ -v` or any other version that isn't installed throws an error, as expected.

What am I missing?

Comment: Of course, temporarily uninstalling all but version 4.2.2 of the rails gem might help as a work around. But why this error occurs I cannot say. Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: If you have installed rails through rvm try this: `rvm use 4.2.2 --default` this will make 4.2.2 as default and let me know if it works?

Comment: @ShyamBhimani rvm manages Ruby versions, not Rails. As I mentioned above, this error happens when using ruby-2.2.1 but not when using a different version, such as 2.3.0.

Comment: https://strandcode.com/2013/07/11/ruby-version-manager-rvm-overview-for-rails-newbs/ this would be helpful to solve your issue go through with this.